# In angularjs ngclick is not working from ajax response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In Angularjs 
    We are get the Ajax response from Codeigniter controller, How can we  assign that response to HTML page and ng-click is not working that response.

Advice me.

Comment: Use $compile to compile the html to the $scope.Should work after that

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I have got the answer.

Angular script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
     myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.buttonHtml = "<a ng-click='samlpleMessage("sample123")'>click me</a>";
            $scope.samlpleMessage = function(message) {
                alert(message);
            }

        });
    myApp.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
              // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'compile' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
      };
    }]);
```

I have adding compile function into angular script. then view page I have add a this code.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div compile="buttonHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Solved this issue.
Thanks :)